# linq to sql merge dates into groups

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I have a simple sql query like so:

```
SELECT dt AS 'startDate'
 , dt AS 'endDate'
FROM
    WorkCalendar
WHERE
     dt BETWEEN dateadd(yy, datediff(yy, 0, getdate()), 0) AND dateadd(MILLISECOND, -3, dateadd(YEAR, datediff(YEAR, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))
     AND isWorkDay = 0
```

This returns all dates from my table containing days free from work in current year.

This is sample output:

```
startDate               endDate
2012-01-01 00:00:00     2012-01-01 00:00:00
2012-01-06 00:00:00     2012-01-06 00:00:00
2012-01-07 00:00:00     2012-01-07 00:00:00
2012-01-08 00:00:00     2012-01-08 00:00:00
2012-01-14 00:00:00     2012-01-14 00:00:00
2012-01-15 00:00:00     2012-01-15 00:00:00
2012-01-21 00:00:00     2012-01-21 00:00:00
2012-01-22 00:00:00     2012-01-22 00:00:00
```

What I would like to do is to group near dates like so:

```
startDate               endDate
2012-01-01 00:00:00     2012-01-01 00:00:00
2012-01-06 00:00:00     2012-01-08 00:00:00
2012-01-14 00:00:00     2012-01-15 00:00:00
2012-01-21 00:00:00     2012-01-22 00:00:00
```

If I have 2 or more days that are one by another I would like to join them into groups.

I would like this done with linq to sql as it will be simpler for me to use in webservice, but simple sql will do the trick :)

Comment: What have tried already?

Comment: Right now I'm using first part, but I've tried building recursive query, but I've killed my server doing joins where endDate+1=startDate :/

Comment: Could you show us the LINQ to SQL query(s) you've already written?

Comment: I've got only SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got something like this:

```
WITH d (d1) 
 AS (SELECT dt 
     FROM   workcalendar 
     WHERE  dt BETWEEN Dateadd(yy, Datediff(yy, 0, Getdate()), 0) AND 
                               Dateadd(millisecond, -3, 
                               Dateadd(year, Datediff(year, 
                                             0, 
                                             Getdate()) + 1 
                               , 0)) 
            AND isworkday = 0) 
SELECT Z1.d1 AS startDate, 
   Z2.d1 AS endDate 
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() 
             OVER ( 
               ORDER BY A.d1) AS 'ID', 
           A.d1 
    FROM   d AS A 
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                       FROM   d AS C 
                       WHERE  A.d1 = Dateadd(d, 1, C.d1))) AS Z1, 
   (SELECT Row_number() 
             OVER ( 
               ORDER BY A.d1) AS 'ID', 
           A.d1 
    FROM   d AS A 
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                       FROM   d AS C 
                       WHERE  A.d1 = Dateadd(d, -1, C.d1))) AS Z2 
WHERE  Z1.id = Z2.id
```

But any comments and optimization are welcome :)

Comment: I thought you were looking for LINQ to SQL to express this?

Comment: Yes I am, but don't know how to convert this :/